# getWritableDatabase cannot be resolved

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Im following a youtube video on how to make a sqlite database for a android app and I have run into this problem:

```
mSQLiteDb =  mMyHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

at this line it says that `getWritableDatabase()` cannot be resolved

can anyone help me to fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sqlitedb;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mNameEt;
private EditText mPhoneEt;
private Object mMyHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mNameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mPhoneEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mMyHelper = new MyHelper(MainActivity.this,"STUDDB",null,1);
    mSQLiteDb =  mMyHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertData(View view) {

}

public void readData(View view) {
}
}
```

**MyHelper.java**

```
package com.example.sqlitedb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public MyHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table student(_id integer primary key, name text, phone text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

thank you

Comment: I strongly suggest you migrate to Room Persistent Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
private Object mMyHelper;
```

with:

```
private MyHelper mMyHelper;
```